Let $X$ ,$Y$ be two $n\times n$ real matrices such that $XY=X^2+X+I$.

Let $X$ ,$Y$ be two $n\times n$ real matrices such that $XY=X^2+X+I$.Which of the following statements are necessarily true?

1.$X$ is invertible.2.$X+I$ is invertible.3.$XY=YX$.4.$Y$ is invertible.
Since $XY=X^2+X+I\implies X(Y-X-I)=I$.Therefore $X$ is invertible.Now as $X$ is invertible therefore $Y=X+X^{-1}+I$.So, $YX=(X+X^{-1}+I)X=X^2+X+I=XY$.
Thus option (1) and (3) are correct.For option(2) I have a matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}_{2\times 2}$$ Which satisfies the given condition but then $X+I$ is a zero matrix.So option (2) is incorrect.I am unable to solve option(4).I tried to show that $Y$ is not invertible always by trying counterexamples but did not find any counterexample.(may be $Y$ is invertible).

Can you find a $2\times 2$ matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^{2}+\lambda +1$?

@geetha290krm Yes.Let the first row of this matrix  is [-2,3] and second row is [-1,1] then it will give the desired characteristic polynomial.

For such a  matrix $X$,  $X^{2}+X+1=0$. Take $Y=0$.

@geetha290krm using Cayley Hamilton theorem ??

Yes, that is what I meant.

Consider $X=\left(\begin{matrix}-1&1\\-1&0\end{matrix}\right)$. It's easy to verify that $XY=X^2+X+I=0$. Since $X$ is invertible, then $Y$ cannot be invertible.

What is $Y$ in your case? Why not just take $Y=0$?

@DietrichBurde If $X$ and $Y$ are both invertible then $XY$ is also invertible.But in this case $XY=0$ and $X$ is invertible so $Y$ must not be invertible.

@DietrichBurde Infact $Y$ does not other choices except being a zero matrix.As $XY=0$ and $X$ is invertible therefore $Y$ must be zero.

@SandeepTiwari So $4.$ is false, because we just take $Y=0$ and this matrix $X$.

@DietrichBurde Yes sir.Thank you for your valuable comments.
